# Memory allocation and process memory use

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

I would like to understand why data dynamically allocated called multiple times uses so much memory than the one directly specified on code or allocated with a single call of `malloc`.

## Examples

As example, I made the following two codes, in C:

test1.c: **int x is allocated with `malloc`**

```
int main (void)
{
    int *x;
    int i, n=1048576; //n=1024*1024;

    printf("size = %lu\n", n* sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *x=i;
    }
    printf("Look at top and then press something to finish.");fflush(stdout);
    getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

I did not use **free** here to keep it simple.
When the program is waiting for interaction, I look at the top function in another terminal, and it shows me this:

```
PID  USER   PR  NI  VIRT   RES    SHR  S  %CPU %MEM  TIME+   COMMAND                                    
1384 root   20  0   41300  34076  1300 S  0.0  3.3   0:00.47 test1
```

test2.c: **int x is not allocated dynamically**

```
int main (void)
{
    int x[1048576]; //x[1024*1024]
    int i, n=1048576;

    printf("size = %lu\n", n* sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x[i]=i;
    }
    printf("Look at top and then press something to finish.");fflush(stdout);
    getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

And top shows me:

```
PID  USER   PR  NI  VIRT    RES    SHR  S  %CPU %MEM  TIME+   COMMAND                                    
1352 root   20  0   12404   5500   1304 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.05 test2
```

I also did a third code, which has the same result that test2, where I used:

```
x = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x[i]=i;
    }
```

Why so much difference on the memory use of the processes? That is because malloc request new memory pages and are there memory being wasted? Or `malloc` allocates more memory?

test1 uses **3.3%** of the total memory and test2 uses **0.5%**.

## Environment:

I am executing those tests on Centos 5 64 bits inside docker.

Memory on the virtual environment:

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            995          98         845           3          51         808
Swap:          1162         194         967
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Malloc vs custom allocator: Malloc has a lot of overhead. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064850/malloc-vs-custom-allocator-malloc-has-a-lot-of-overhead-why)

Comment: Take a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540845/linux-heap-structure-and-the-behaviour-with-malloc-and-free

Comment: This is related to 'malloc vs custom allocator', but not quite the same as that.

Comment: This is also related to SO 1054085 (Linux heap structure and behaviour of malloc and free), but not quite the same.  (Or maybe I'm just being unusually fussy today — not sure.)

Comment: Note that test2 is allocating space from the stack which is pre-allocated at program load and start up time. The third example does a one time allocation from the heap, so it should use more memory than the second example. Getting back to test2, a 4 megabyte+ stack seems unusually large. I'm wondering if a smart compiler would detect that x[] is local to main and uses a static like variable (from program memory instead of stack).

Comment: @rcgldr: the overhead of 16 bytes or so on a 4 MiB heap allocation is negligible, whereas the overhead of 4-12 bytes (possibly 4-28 bytes overhead) on each of a million or so allocations of 4 bytes is rather significant.  Also, a million separate allocations are not readily manageable: you need an array of a million pointers to hold the million separate values, which leads to messy freeing, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - my point was that the memory used in test 2 would be the same regardless of the size of x[], since it's allocated from the stack, which in turn is preallocated at load / startup. Test 3 should also allocate the same amount of space for the stack, and then in addition, allocate 4 MB of ram from the heap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every memory allocation has to be tracked so that `free()` can release the space for reuse.  In practice, that means there's a minimum memory size that's allocated; it can be 8 or 16 bytes for a 32-bit program and 16-32 bytes for a 64-bit program (it depends on the system and the version of the C library in use).

When you allocate the one million integers separately, each one of them uses 8-32 bytes, so you've actually used 8-32 MiB of memory.  When you allocate the one million integers in a single array on the stack, you're using 4 MiB of memory.

Hence you see a substantial difference in the process size.

The first program leaks almost all the memory, of course, but that's tangential to the question you're asking.

Comment: Jonathan nice answer! However, notice that the last sentence might not be needed, since OP mentioned that he deliberately not included the `free()` for simplicity. :)

Comment: Yes; my last sentence isn't 100% necessary, but it isn't harmful either.  The simplicity gained by leaving `free` out of the question is significant; the code would need 'a million' pointers to store the million allocated integers, adding to the memory overhead (4 or 8 MiB more needed).

Answer (score 2):

The system needs to do some housekeeping every time a user asks for some memory. That's should come in mind when just calling free with just your pointer suffices for the system to de-allocate its memory.

So, in your first example, you request memory `n` times, while on the second just once. The memory that you intend to use is the same, but the information the system has to "remember" is not.